# .htaccess redirect when specific path is found

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was struggling the last few days to write a proper solution for my `.htaccess` so that I can redirect `(http://www.)domain.com/path/anotherpath` to `https://www2.domain.com/path/anotherpath`.

I have managed to make it work as below:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} www\.domain\.com\path\anotherpath
RewriteRule (.*) https://www2.domain.com/path/anotherpath [R=301,L]
```

However, this solution doesn't seem to work when I need to redirect pages that belong to deeper levels like for example: domain.com/path/anotherpath/level1/level2 (level1 and level2 are dynamic). Now it redirects only when a specific full url is detected.

How can I make this work without defining the full urls in my htaccess?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(shop)(/.*|)$ http://www2.%1/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work the way I described. So I guess my description wasn't very good. What I need to do is that whenever http://www.domain.com/path/anotherpath is detected in the url, change it to https://www2.domain.com/path/anotherpath even if more levels are following the url like: http://www.domain.com/path/anotherpath/level1/level2. So the redirected url will become https://www2.domain.com/path/anotherpath/level1/level2. It's just that level1/level2 are dynamic and I cannot define them in .htaccess.

Comment: I understood your question and gave my answer for that only. Can you post your .htaccess in your question or try the edited answer of mine.

Comment: Here's how I adjusted my .htacces:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# REDIRECTS THE SHOP PAGE TO HTTPS WWW2 url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(mydomain\.com\en\shop)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www2.%1%{mydomain.com/en/shop} [R=301,L]

Comment: That means you didn't follow my answer. This line in your .htaccess: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(mydomain\.com\en\shop)$ [NC]` is WRONG. It should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]`. Remember `%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches your host name not full URL.

Comment: I see what you mean but my problem is that I don't want to redirect the whole website to https://www2. I just need to redirect when the shop is been visited. Thus, www.domain.com/en/shop (or more levels like en/shop/cars/bmw) becomes https://www2.domain.com/en/shop (/cars/bmw). But not redirect www.domain.com/support/faq to www2.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear on this. Anyway I just edited my answer accordingly. Try it now.

Comment: I know I was probably unclear. You saved my day! I thought I had to define the exact path that needed to be redirected, but I was wrong. Thank you very much for your valuable help and advice.